# MSBuild will not execute targets in parallel

Tags: msbuild

I am trying to understand why MSBuild does not execute targets in parallel. Given a simple test.proj:

```
<Project>
    <ItemGroup>
      <_Project Include="$(MSBuildThisFileFullPath)"
                Targets="_T1" />
      <_Project Include="$(MSBuildThisFileFullPath)"
                Targets="_T2" />
    </ItemGroup>
  <Target Name="Build">
    <MSBuild BuildInParallel="true"
             Projects="@(_Project)"
             Targets="%(_Project.Targets)" />
  </Target>
  <Target Name="_T1">
    <Exec Command="ping -n 3 127.0.0.1" />
  </Target>
  <Target Name="_T2">
    <Exec Command="ping -n 3 127.0.0.1" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

and command:

```
msbuild /m /t:Build test.proj
```

_T1 and _T2 targets are executed sequentially. I must be missing something really simple, but I cannot figure out what it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are invoking batching.

The `%(_Project.Targets)` value to the `Targets` parameter is creating batches based on distinct values of the `Targets` metadata. There is a batch for `_T1` and a batch for `_T2`.

The `MSBuild` task is being invoked twice in sequence, once for each batch.

See "[MSBuild batching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-batching?view=vs-2022)".

Try the following instead to pass multiple projects to one invocation of the `MSBuild` task:

```
    <MSBuild BuildInParallel="true"
             Projects="@(_Project)"
             Targets="_T1" />
```

### Update

The code above is not correct for the example scenario in the question. The `MSBuild` task recognizes that the two items in `@(_Project)` are duplicates and executes the project once. If two different project files were used they wouldn't be duplicates and both would be run.

The items in `@(_Project)` will also not be duplicates if they have different metadata. There are special `Properties` and `AdditionalProperties` metadata that can be used with the [MSBuild task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-task?view=vs-2022). See "[Pass properties to projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-task?view=vs-2022#pass-properties-to-projects)".

In the example code below:

- I added different `Properties` metadata to each project (and removed the `Targets` metadata).
- I added a `Ping` target. The `Ping` target runs different targets based on the passed property of `PingDependsOn`.

```
<Project>
  <ItemGroup>
    <_Project Include="$(MSBuildThisFileFullPath)">
      <Properties>PingDependsOn=_T1</Properties>
    </_Project>
    <_Project Include="$(MSBuildThisFileFullPath)">
      <Properties>PingDependsOn=_T2</Properties>
    </_Project>
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="Build">
    <MSBuild BuildInParallel="true"
             Projects="@(_Project)"
             Targets="Ping" />
  </Target>

  <Target Name="Ping" DependsOnTargets="$(PingDependsOn)" />

  <Target Name="_T1">
    <Exec Command="ping -n 3 127.0.0.1" />
  </Target>

  <Target Name="_T2">
    <Exec Command="ping -n 3 127.0.0.1" />
  </Target>

</Project>
```

The project can be run as

```
dotnet msbuild parallel.proj /v:n
```

or

```
msbuild parallel.proj /m
```

(The switches are different because the dotnet tool runs the embedded MSBuild as `/v:m /m` and the standalone MSBuild runs as `/v:n /m:1`. )

A slightly edited example of the resulting output shows interleaved lines of text from targets `_T1` and `_T2`:

```
     1>Project "parallel.proj" on node 1 (default targets).
     1>Project "parallel.proj" (1) is building "parallel.proj" (1:2) on
        node 1 (Ping target(s)).
     1>_T1:
         ping -n 3 127.0.0.1
     1>Project "parallel.proj" (1) is building "parallel.proj" (1:3) on
        node 2 (Ping target(s)).
     1>_T2:
         ping -n 3 127.0.0.1
     1>_T1:

         Pinging 127.0.0.1 with 32 bytes of data:
         Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
     1>_T2:

         Pinging 127.0.0.1 with 32 bytes of data:
         Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
     1>_T1:
         Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
     1>_T2:
         Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
     1>_T1:
         Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128

         Ping statistics for 127.0.0.1:
             Packets: Sent = 3, Received = 3, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
         Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
             Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms
     1>Done Building Project "parallel.proj" (Ping target(s)).
     1>_T2:
         Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128

         Ping statistics for 127.0.0.1:
             Packets: Sent = 3, Received = 3, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
         Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
             Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms
     1>Done Building Project "parallel.proj" (Ping target(s)).
     1>Done Building Project "parallel.proj" (default targets).

Build succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:02.13
```

Comment: It executed target _T1 only once.

Comment: I added an update to the answer. I didn't account for the same project file being used.